# Saber el valor de determinado digito de un numero de varias cifras

Tags: java

Hola soy alumno de profesorado en informatica y estoy viendo programacion en java, me piden un ejercicio que me pide **determinar el valor del primer y ultimo digito en un numero de 3 cifras**. Alguien me puede ayudar? Como hago para saber el valor de la tercera cifra por ejemplo. En JAVA por favor

Answer (score 0):

con el operador de modulo (%),que te devuelve el residuo de una division y asi puedes obtener el ultimo digit

```
int numero=635; 
int ultimo=numero%10;
System.out.println(ultimo);
```

espero te ayude de algo

Comment: Muchas gracias Nestor, me sirvio tu ayuda!